# Python doesn't see a library graph_tool

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, graph-tool

I have installed the "graph-tool" library. I used am instruction from official site https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/wikis/installation-instructions (the option "Installation via package managers". I use Anaconda distributive (I included it in the PATH) instead of system version of Python. And there is a problem... When I use system python it sees this library but my Anaconda doesn't...
What should I do that my Anaconda will see it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu you will, as far as I know, have to compile graph-tool from scratch in order for it to work correctly when using anaconda python.